# Why is the font only rendering sometimes even though it always downloads?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, netlify

The word "TWIST" in the hero section of this site: https://pretzelnight.com/ should have Pacifico font, but it is only loading sometimes (try refreshing to reproduce the problem). When I look at network requests, it seems like it's always downloading it, just not necessarily always loading it.

Using @next/font": "^13.1.4"

_app.tsx

```js
import { ShopProvider } from '@/context/shopContext'
import '../styles/tailwind.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { Montserrat, Pacifico } from '@next/font/google'

const montserrate = Montserrat({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-montserrat',
})

const pacifico = Pacifico({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-pacifico',
  weight: ['400'],
})

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ShopProvider>
      <main
        className={`${montserrate.variable} ${pacifico.variable} font-sans`}
      >
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </main>
    </ShopProvider>
  )
}
```

The relevant section in hero:

```js
<h1 className="text-4xl font-semibold text-[#F15B50] lg:text-6xl">
     <span className="font-pacifico font-normal">TWIST</span> IT UP
</h1>
```

tailwind.config.js

```js
const { fontFamily } = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

module.exports = {
  content: [
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['var(--font-montserrat)', ...fontFamily.sans],
        pacifico: ['var(--font-pacifico)', ...fontFamily.serif],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Font-display "optional"

Currently, you're allowing the browser to skip rendering with the custom font file

```
@font-face {
    font-family: __Pacifico_a032f9;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: optional;
    src: url(/_next/static/media/c89cfa4ee44cbc90.woff2) format("woff2");
}
```

From [smashing magazine: "Barry Pollard – A New Way To Reduce Font Loading Impact: CSS Font Descriptors"](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/05/reduce-font-loading-impact-css-descriptors/#using-font-display-optional-can-solve-foit-and-fout-at-a-cost)

> The other option is to use font-display: optional. This option
> basically makes web fonts optional, or to put differently, if the font
> isn’t there by the time the page needs it, then it’s up to the browser
> to never swap it. With this option, we avoid both FOIT and FOUT by
> basically only using fonts that have already been downloaded.

#### Workarounds:

- change font-display to **"swap"** or **"fallback"**
- allow font caching by setting an expiry date.  See also ["How do I leverage browser caching of .woff fonts?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553140/how-do-i-leverage-browser-caching-of-woff-fonts) and ["How to cache fonts in NextJs?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57272055/how-to-cache-fonts-in-nextjs)
- prioritize the download of font files via [`preload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload):
  `<link rel="preload" href="fonts/Pacifico.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">`